# TDS-Protocol with pre-login failure message when connecting to Amazon RDS (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, tds

We are trying to connect from an application installed on a virtual machine to a database as part of an AWS RDS in the cloud.

There are several routers and firewalls between the source and the target system and there is also NATting happening of the source IP.

A connection test in PowerShell works.

[image: See screenshot]

However, when trying to connect to the database with a connection string from within the application, a TDS pre-login handshake error message appears.

[image: See screenshot]

A traffic capture with Wireshark also did not provide a clear solution to the error.

We have also tested the connection to the database from SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) and the same error message appears.

When testing the connection from a different virtual machine the problem does not occur.

So it is not due to a specific application.

My guess is that somehow the SQL Server can't understand the pre-login message and kills the connection.

Does anybody know how to analze this pre-login message in Wireshark to derive further possible solutions?

We turned off the encryption on the AWS RDS but this did not help.

This is the Wireshark capture:

[image: See screenshot]

Comment: _We turned off the encryption on the AWS RDS but this did not help._ Which encryption? EBS? TDE? TLS? AE?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the TCP/IP Provider on the client side? Sounds like you could be defaulting to one of the other two providers: Named Pipes or Shared Memory. What was happening in Wireshark? Was it actually sending packets only to tcp/1433, or was it targeting other ports and protocols (e.g.: udp) against the destination IP as well?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning
The TLS encryption

Comment: @AlwaysLearning
I have added the Wireshark capture

Comment: TDS Prelogin message is the first message sent by the client, and so this error indicates a failure of the server to send the expected response packet.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft
How can you be sure it is the server that has a problem and not the client allready or a firewall between client and server?

Comment: Could be any of those.  All we know is that the client isn't getting a response to the TDS prelogin message.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft
But can we say for sure that the pre-login message is reaching the server?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft
Do you know how to capture the traffic going back to the client?

Comment: I have the following failure message in the SQL Log:

Comment: I now have the following SQL error message from the SQL-Audit-Log
Network error code 0x274c occurred while establishing a connection; the connection has been closed.
total 40096 ms, enqueued 0 ms, network writes 0 ms, network reads 40096 ms, establishing SSL 0 ms, network reads during SSL 0 ms, network writes during SSL 0 ms, secure calls during SSL 0 ms, enqueued during SSL 0 ms, negotiating SSPI 0 ms, network reads during SSPI 0 ms, network writes during SSPI 0 ms, secure calls during SSPI 0 ms, enqueued during SSPI 0 ms, validating login 0 ms, including user-defined login processing 0 ms.